# How can I get the android window size using Java as programming language for android automation testing?

Tags: automated-testing, java, android, mobile-automation

How to detect the screen size for different android phones?

I want the coordinate values like *`startx`, `starty`, `endx`, endy*.
With that I can use the swipe method which takes these coordinates as parameters.

I used 
`Dimension size = driver.manage().window().getSize();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the screen width and screen height using the below code:

```
  Dimension dimensions = driver.manage().window().getSize();
  int screenWidth = dimensions.getWidth();
  int screenHeight = dimensions.getHeight();
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few methods to do this,

1. `getSize()` methods

   `Display screensize = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); Point size = new Point(); screensize.getSize(size); int width = size.x; int height = size.y;`
2. Ge default display size:

   `WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE); Display screensize = wm.getDefaultDisplay();`
3. `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` methods

   `Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();  int width = display.getWidth();  // deprecated int height = display.getHeight();  // deprecated`
4. `DisplayMetrics()` method:

   `DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics(); getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics); int height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;  int width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;`

Hope this helps you! :)